# Function calling function in c++

Tags: c++, functional-programming

I'm trying to write the “plus2” and “plus3” functions that implement the functions, respectively, and are defined as follows.

f is a function such that expression (x) (y) should result in the value of x + y.

g is a function such that expression (x) (y) (z) should result in the value of x + y + z. Here, x, y, z are integers.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
std::function<int(int)> plus2(int n) {
  return [n](int x) { return x + n; };
}
std::function<int(int)> plus3(int f(int), int n) {
  return [f, n](int x) { return f(n) + x; };
}
int main() {
  std::cout<<plus2(1)(2)<<" "<<plus3(1)(2)(3);
  return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT should be: 3 6

I get an error

> too few arguments to function ‘std::function<int(int)> plus3(int
> (*)(int), int)’

Function plus2 works fine. Could you explain me where I'm making mistake in function plus3?

Comment: `int f(int)` - this means you intend to pass a function pointer as argument. But instead you are calling it as `plus3(1)` - the number 1 is not a function pointer

Comment: Can you walk us through how you expect `plus3`'s arguments to be resolved? It isn't clear to me what your expectations are regarding how this code is supposed to work.

Answer (score 2):

> Function plus2 works fine.

Because `plus2` is a function that expects 1 parameter and returns a function that expects 1 parameter.

`plus3` on the other hand is a function that expects 2 parameters. You cannot call it with only one parameter. You can turn it into a function that expects one parameter and returns a callable that returns a callable.

I suppose this is just an exercise to learn lambdas, because otherwise I see no reason to write the functions like this. At least you should use `auto` return type to avoid unnecessary conversion to `std::function` (*):

```
#include <iostream>

auto plus3(int n) {
    return [n](int a) { return [b=a+n](int c){ return b+c;} ;};
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){    
    std::cout << plus3(1)(2)(3);
}
```

(*): `std::function` is **not** the type you should use whenever you want to pass a callable around. Rather it is the type to be used when you need one type that can store any kind of callable. `std::function` uses type erasure to achieve that. If you do not need that then you do not need `std::function`.

Comment: thanks, could you write me what auto in this case is? I tried with `std::function<int(int)>` but it doesn't work

Comment: `auto` gets deduced as the type of the lambda expression. Also in `plus2` `std::function<int(int)>` is *not* the type of `[f, n](int x) { return f(n) + x; }`. Lambdas are of some unnamed type. Usually you need not know the type. It can be converted to `std::function`, but here it isnt necessary

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are practicing the subject of currying in functional programming ([Currying - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)).

If you want to write `plus3` as a curried function you can do the following (no change in `plus2`):

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

auto plus2(int n) {
    return [n](int x) { return x + n; };
}

auto plus3(int n) {
    return [n](int m) {
        return [n, m](int x) { return x + n + m; }; };
}

int main() {
    std::cout << plus2(1)(2) << " " << plus3(1)(2)(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: isnt the point of currying that `plus3` reuses `plus2` ? Your code isnt doing that

Comment: As far as I understand currying, it means to convert a function receiving multiple arguments, to function returning another function etc., each consuming one of the arguments. Didn't think code reuse is relevant to this concept (although I agree it's better to reuse).

Comment: I don't know it was a honest question. Actually I was suspecting that OP is trying to practice something like that, but I wasnt sure what it was

Answer (score 2):

`plus3` should take an `int` and produce a function.
It should not take a function and an `int`.

The resulting function should take an `int` and then proceed as `plus2`.

It's a nice touch to reuse `plus2`:

```
std::function<std::function<int(int)>(int)> plus3(int n) {
    return [n](int x) { return plus2(n+x); };
}
```

Slightly more readable with a type alias:

```
using int_to_int = std::function<int(int)>;
std::function<int_to_int(int)> plus3(int n) {
    return [n](int x) { return plus2(n+x); };
}
```

and even more readable with `auto` (although it's not equivalent since it doesn't give the same type):

```
auto plus3(int n) {
    return [n](int x) { return plus2(n+x); };
}
```

and now you can generalize:

```
template<size_t n>
auto plus(int x)
{
    return [x](int y) { return plus<n-1>(x+y); };
}

template<>
auto plus<1>(int x) { return x; }

int main() {
    std::cout << plus<2>(1)(2) << std::endl << plus<4>(1)(2)(3)(4) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: nice solution, and also generic :)